# Setting batch_size in data_param for Caffe has no effect

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

When I set `'batch_size'` in [deploy.prototxt file](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_googlenet/deploy.prototxt) in Google deep dream *bvlc_googlenet* to lower GPU memory requirements, it has no effect on speed nor memory requirements. It's as if it was ignored. I know the file itself (deploy.prototxt) is being used because other changes are reflected in results so that's not the issue. I also tried to set batch_size on all related layers as well ("inception_4c/1x1", etc), again no difference.

This is how I'm setting it:

```
layer {
  name: "inception_4c/output"
  type: "Concat"
  bottom: "inception_4c/1x1"
  bottom: "inception_4c/3x3"
  bottom: "inception_4c/5x5"
  bottom: "inception_4c/pool_proj"
  top: "inception_4c/output"
  data_param {
    batch_size 1
  }
}
```

When I time the runtime of the script, it's the same with batch_size 1 and with batch_size 512, there is no difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data_param` is a parameter of the input data layer. You can set `batch_size` only for the input and this value propagates through the network.

In the [*deploy.prototxt*](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_googlenet/deploy.prototxt#L3) the batch size is set by the first `'input_dim'` argument ([third line](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_googlenet/deploy.prototxt#L3)), try changing this value and see if it has any effect on the memory consumption of your network.

The first few lines of the *deploy.prototxt* file should be interpreted as

```
input: "data"  # the "top" name of input layer
input_dim: 10  # 4th dimension - batch size
input_dim: 3   # 3rd dimension - number of channels
input_dim: 224 # 2nd dimension - height of input
input_dim: 224 # 1st dimension - width of input
```

Thus, you expect at your fist conv layer (`"conv1/7x7_s2"`) a "bottom" named "data" with shape `10`-by-`3`-by-`224`-by-`224`.

Comment: This changed "Memory required for data" output so it affects something. But the process is still running out of memory. Memory required is now only 50MB and the graphics card has capacity of 4GB, yet it's running out of memory "syncedmem.cpp:51] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (2 vs. 0)  out of memory". Any ideas?

Comment: @Sergey I'm not familiar with the model/setting of the "deep dream" system. but it sounds like (a) are you sharing the GPU with other processes? (b) is it possible that memory allocations in GPU are not "free"d?

Comment: According to "nvidia-smi" command, the memory consumed by the python script in question goes all the way from 10MB (before) to 4GB (when running script). It's in a server environment.

Comment: @Sergey hoe many processes does the server run? is all the memory used by a single process?

Comment: @Sergey can you run the script line-by-line in debug and monitor the GPU mem at the same time?

Comment: It's running only one process that requires large amount of GPU memory. But I've just found that "Memory required for data" is the same for all different sizes of images. Real memory usage changes with different image sizes, but this quoted number is always only dependant on configuration of deploy.prototext. So even though "Memory required for data" is only 50MB, this number doesn't represent total memory consumption. https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2387 I'm trying to figure out how to calculate real memory usage.